# Switch error: Expected member name or constructor call - what's wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'd like to make a switch on my 3 cases, but I'm getting an error I can't solve:

Error: Expected member name or constructor call after type name

There must be something I've overlooked since I've been already using similar code. But now I have almost an empty project and can't figure out what's wrong?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

enum MyStateStatus {
    case Ready
    case Running
    case Stopped
}

@IBAction func actionPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    switch MyStateStatus {
    case MyStateStatus.Ready:
        print("I'm ready")
    default:
        print("other")
    }
}
```

I'm using Swift, Xcode 6.3.2

UPDATE: Replaced `println()` with `print()` for Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7 compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example your are applying the switch to the enum declaration itself, but you have to switch over an object that contains one of the possible enum values.

For example:

```
var currentState: MyStateStatus = .Ready

@IBAction func actionPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    switch currentState {
    case .Ready:
        println("I'm ready")
    default:
        println("other")
    }
}
```